# What literary term is applicable to "awful majesty?"

Tags: rhetoric, irony, literary-device, rhetorical-devices, oxymoron

What would "awful majesty" be considered? I believe there is a literary term for this kind of contradictory statement – perhaps *irony?* Or is there another word for it?

Comment: It's only "contradictory" if you interpret ***awful*** in the current sense of ***extremely bad***. But you're talking about a collocation that isn't normally used at all today, except in recognition/allusion to the way it was used a couple of centuries ago (with the meaning ***awe-inspiring***). Consequently I'm unclear as to what exactly is being asked here. Can you give a more meaningful example?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, there would be no literary term for it, because it's a straight-forward phrase; *majesty* means "greatness" and *awful* means "inspiring awe" and it's straight-forward and natural to talk of greatness inspiring awe.

If someone was writing today and wanted to deliberately play on the fact that *awful* has (relatively recently) also gained a sense meaning "very bad", then they would be using it as an *apparent oxymoron*. It's not an oxymoron because oxymora have a real opposition between the senses, rather than just bringing other opposing senses to mind. An apparent oxymoron can though be enough to bring a sense of irony to an otherwise rather plain description, because the contradiction could work in the back of the reader's mind. This wouldn't work well with *awful majesty* though, as that phrase has too often been used with its plain meaning for the contradictory interpretation to come through strongly.

(If someone really wanted to say that the greatness was very bad then it would be oxymoronic, but it's hard to think of how this would be done, and if so it would probably be a bad choice, for the ironic reason that they would be hampered by the "inspiring awe" sense of *aweful* coming to mind even to many modern readers when followed by *majesty*).

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is *oxymoron*:

> a figure of speech by which a locution produces an incongruous, seemingly self-contradictory effect

I suppose it's worth nothing, though, that *awful* can also mean "inspiring awe" (though no one ever uses it that way), which would make it not an oxymoron at all.

Answer (score -1):

The term you are looking for is *oxymoron*.